# Asp Core webpack doesn't stop building

Tags: node.js, webpack, asp.net-core

When running my project in debug mode, I am observing the following in the output window:

```
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Message","time":"2017-12-12T20:25:01.5120820Z","tags":{"ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.1.1"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"webpack building...","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development","{OriginalFormat}":"webpack building...","CategoryName":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices"}}}}
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices:Information: webpack built 9d5e943444c01ed925e7 in 181ms
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Message","time":"2017-12-12T20:25:01.6641045Z","tags":{"ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.1.1"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"webpack built 9d5e943444c01ed925e7 in 181ms","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development","{OriginalFormat}":"webpack built 9d5e943444c01ed925e7 in 181ms","CategoryName":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices"}}}}
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices:Information: webpack building...
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Message","time":"2017-12-12T20:25:02.0043764Z","tags":{"ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.1.1"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"webpack building...","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development","{OriginalFormat}":"webpack building...","CategoryName":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices"}}}}
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices:Information: webpack built 9d5e943444c01ed925e7 in 164ms
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Message","time":"2017-12-12T20:25:02.1066642Z","tags":{"ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.1.1"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"webpack built 9d5e943444c01ed925e7 in 164ms","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development","{OriginalFormat}":"webpack built 9d5e943444c01ed925e7 in 164ms","CategoryName":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices"}}}}
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices:Information: webpack building...
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Message","time":"2017-12-12T20:25:02.3485565Z","tags":{"ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.1.1"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"webpack building...","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development","{OriginalFormat}":"webpack building...","CategoryName":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices"}}}}
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices:Information: webpack built 9d5e943444c01ed925e7 in 78ms
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Message","time":"2017-12-12T20:25:02.4149013Z","tags":{"ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.1.1"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"webpack built 9d5e943444c01ed925e7 in 78ms","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development","{OriginalFormat}":"webpack built 9d5e943444c01ed925e7 in 78ms","CategoryName":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices"}}}}
```

And it never stops. The only installation of nodejs (0.12.7) in the project is for npm (3.5.2).

Is this a problem with my webpack configuration or is there something I need to do with node?

Edit:
Here is my webpack.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;
const bundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';

module.exports = (env) => {
const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
return [{
    stats: { modules: false },
    entry: { 'main': './ClientApp/boot.tsx' },
    resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'] },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, bundleOutputDir),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: 'dist/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: 'awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true' },
            { test: /\.css$/, use: isDevBuild ? ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] : ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ use: 'css-loader?minimize' }) },
            { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CheckerPlugin(),
        new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
            context: __dirname,
            manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
        })
    ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
        // Plugins that apply in development builds only
        new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
            filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
            moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(bundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
        })
    ] : [
        // Plugins that apply in production builds only
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('site.css')
    ])
}];
};
```

Comment: Is this related to your previous question with pretty much the same content? Please don’t make new questions about the same thing. Probably the problem is your webpack config.

Comment: Any specific idea on what sort of problem? At this point I'm not sure why it's even happening. It looks like it builds successfully. So why is it looping if it's successful?